# jQuery - callback for toggle (show/hide) within event handler

Tags: jquery, event-handling, callback, toggle

I've had this working fine:

```
$('#RCH'+r).on('click',function(e){$('#RSC'+r).find('.rct,.rcp').toggle();});
```

At the end of all the toggles, though, I want to call a function `rs(1);`

PLAN 1: I tried putting the callback on the toggle, but it all goes haywire.

```
$('#RCH'+r).on('click',function(e){
  $('#RSC'+r).find('.rct,.rcp').toggle('',function(){rs(1);});
});
```

The above calls the function `rs(1)` for every occurence of the class (like an `each`). It also undoes what normally happens, so that if `.rcp` was being shown and `.rct` was being hidden, precisely the opposite happens. So Plan 1 makes everything go to hell in a handbasket.

PLAN 2: I also tried putting `rs(1)` after the toggle in the `.on` function (as below).

```
$('#RCH'+r).on('click',function(e){$('#RSC'+r).find('.rct,.rcp').toggle();rs(1);});
```

This method, however, fires `rs(1)` before the toggle has finished, and so the `rs` function doesn't do its job.

So... how can I fire `rs(1);` once AFTER the toggles have finished?

Thanks.

Comment: `toggle()` is instant, so the latter should work?

Comment: I would have thought so, but it doesn't seem so. I'll check :)  [Later] No, it really doesn't appear so. I'm guessing because it cycles through all the instances of the two classes.

Comment: My mistake, everyone. It is instantaneous. But I have recently changed the rs function to accept two arguments, not one. So the function wasn't being called correctly. A thousand pardons. You were right, Matt & Félix :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, firstly, `.toggle()` is instant, so I'll assume you're actually using `.toggle(/* some duration */)`. In this case, you can pass a function which is called after the toggle animation has completed:

```
$('sel').toggle(/* duration */, function () {
  // ...
});
```

If you *are* actually using `.toggle()` but for some reason there is a delay which is making your code fail, you could try this:

```
$('sel').toggle(0, function () {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: I want the toggle to be instantaneous. When I've added the callback, I'm using .toggle('',function(){... which achieves the same as toggle(0,function(){...

Answer (score 0):

```
$.when($('#RCH'+r).on('click',function(e){$('#RSC'+r).find('.rct,.rcp').toggle();}))
  .done(function(){rs(1);});
```

try this one, I hope this works.

Comment: This will fire the function rs(1) after the event handler has been attached, not when the event handler fires, right? I want rs(1) to run when the handler fires (i.e., when the user clicks on RCH3 (if r=3). But thanks for the suggestion :)